# Access Jupyter Notebook over Internet

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a Windows 7 computer that I use to host a Jupyter noteboks for use across my local network. However, I would like to be able to access these notebooks remotely over the internet.

Is this possible?

I've tried researching ways but haven't managed to understand anything. The closest I've got was a guide on how to set it up using AWS (https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5183133) but the key step in this is to set up a "public DNS". However, I haven't found how to set this up in Windows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of free/paid VPN solutions to make virtual network between you and jupyter-notebook host to workaround need of public DNS. [Hamachi](http://logmein.com) for example. I'm talking about case when you just want to access jupyter notebook remotely, not when you want to share it with anyone.